# Unable to access jarfile on bash on windows

Tags: java, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm working with bash on windows, and trying to excute a jar with the command:

```
java -jar /mnt/c/test.jar
```

it doesn't work: "Unable to access jarfile /mnt/c/test.jar"

while I cd to the directory:

```
cd /mnt/c
```

and excute it again, it works:

```
java -jar test.jar
```

It goes wrong if I'm not in the same directory with the jar file. Can anybody explain the reason and give a solution please? Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you put the file not in the root of `C:\` but in a folder?

Comment: You need to specify that you're running a Windows install of Java, and not a Unix install of Java. The path isn't understood by java.exe because it's a Windows install of Java and thus doesn't understand Bash on Windows paths.

Answer (score 4):

The path you're passing is not recognized in java itself due its format since java running the .class bytecode file or jar file that it sees in the class path no matter what you're passing. So add the path to you class path and and execute the jar directly like this as a workaround

`java -cp /mnt/c -jar test.jar`

That you you're adding the jar to your class path while executing the seen jar

The cause of this might be a permission issue since the error says the jar file can't be seen. Using git bash the following works when I'm pointing to my C: partition

`java -jar Intel/app.jar`

and this working even when I'm pointing bash to my D: partition

`java -jar /c/Intel/app.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Try running `java -jar C:\\test.jar`.

The bash command is the one that provides illusion of mount points. The java command receives `/mnt/c/test.jar` as parameter and when actually opening the file the path doesn't exist at the OS Level.